# Python read multiple tables from txt file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very long txt file with data in fixed format. I want to split each block into a table and be able calculate ensemble mean for the months and to plot (contourplot) the ensemble mean.
The table looks like this:

```
     year1 Station_name
          Month1 Month2 Month3
lat1 lat2  153 124 159
lat2 lat3  454 155 546
     year2 Station_name
           Month1 Month2 Month3
lat1 lat2  123 164 354
lat2 lat3  454 495 996
     year3 Station_name
           Month1 Month2 Month3
lat1 lat2  223 224 154
lat2 lat3  654 555 596
```

I tried readline and split but did not achieve the result I wanted, also seems to be pretty slow and long script if calculating for thousends of years (modelling). Also I considert to do it with pandas but was not able to split the blocks into tables correctly.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your real file because we didn't know if Month1 is 01, Jan, January, 1, etc.

Comment: can you show the code you tried?